# I want to retrieve a current user's ID from firebase and write it in another node, but it just keeps denying

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So basically I made a String `mojID` which is equal to firebase's current user, I want to pass it as a child in a node but it says it is a null pointer exception and I have already used it in another parts of a code which does not return the fault.

I am attaching some of my code.

```
final DatabaseReference chatRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatLista");
    chatRef1.child(mojID);
    chatRef1.child(userID);
    chatRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                chatRef1.child("id").setValue(userID);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    final DatabaseReference chatRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatLista");

                chatRef2.child(userID);
                chatRef2.child(mojID);

            chatRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){

                chatRef2.child("id").setValue(mojID);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Then there is function that takes the ID:

```
private void ProvjeriStatus(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null){
        //user ulogovan
        mojID = (String)user.getUid();
    }
    //ako nije vraca na login
    else {
       startActivity(new Intent(this,login.class));
       finish();
    }
}
```

I even tried casting it as you can see it and it just says I don't need a cast, because it is already a String? Then why does it return `null`? The only explanation I have come up with is that it is an object not a string and by that `.child` wants a string as a argument not an object.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UserId via FirebaseUser.. You can refer Below code .. maybe it will help 
    you

```
 FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser;
 DatabaseReference databaseReference;

 currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 databaseReference.child("Users").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("User 
 Id").setValue(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
```

If you want to retrieve UserId from database Refer Below code..

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if ((dataSnapshot.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("UserId").getValue() == null)) {
                databaseReference.child("Users").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("UserId").setValue(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
            } else {
                String Id= (String) dataSnapshot.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("UserId").getValue();

            }
```